# Cambiar de AnchorPane en Javavafx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Estoy probando una interfaz gráfica básica en java para intentar cambiar de escena pulsando un botón.
Tengo el siguiente código:

Mi clase Main con el método main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loaderVentana = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VentanaPrincipal.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Aplicación prueba");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loaderVentana.load()));
        primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Mi clase controlador para la ventana principal:

```
public class ControladorVentanaPrincipal {

@FXML
private Button botonEntrada;



public void cambiarVentana() {


}
```

}

Y luego tengo dos archivos FXML llamados VentanaPrincipal.fxml y VentanaSecundaria.fxml.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al pulsar el botón de VentanaPrincipal (es el que hay en el controlador) se cargue en esa misma ventana la VentanaSecundaria.

En VentanaPrincipal.fxml he implementado el controlador y en el botón el método correspondiente.

He visto varios hilos y videos sobre esto pero siempre obtengo errores o excepciones que no consigo solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola Diego!, para cambiar la escena (`Scene`) de un escenario (`Stage`) necesitamos primero identificar el escenario del que estamos hablando y después establecer la nueva escena.

```
@FXML
private Button botonEntrada;
//Tienes un botón que puedes utilizar para la referencia, pero,
//puedes usar cualquier otro nodo que tengas para hacer esto

@FXML
public void cambiarVentana() {
    try {
        //Tomamos la ventana en la que se encuentra el botón y esa
        //ventana en realidad es el escenario que buscamos
        Stage stage = (Stage) botonEntrada.getScene().getWindow();

        //Ya que tenemos el escenario, necesitamos identificar la otra escena
        Scene s = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("VentanaSecundaria.fxml")));

        //Por último cambiamos la escena
        stage.setScene(s);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Para los posibles errores que pueden ocurrir, debes asegurarte que:

- El `FXML` esta bien enlazado a su controlador.
- Tienes el método `cambiarVentana()` en la acción del botón.
- Los recursos están en la misma carpeta.
- Asegurarse de escribir bien los nombres de los recursos, por ejemplo si es `VentanaSecundaria.fxml` escribirlo igual.
- Que el botón en el `FXML` tenga en su campo de id el valor de `botonEntrada`

Espero te sirva, ¡suerte!

Comment: No he conseguido tampoco realizarlo de esta forma. Me da error de compilación al instanciar Scene porque me pide un parámetro de tipo Parent. También lo he intentado con este tipo pero me lanza una excepción.

Comment: Una gran disculpa Diego, confundí el llamado del Parent, ya corregí el error.